# NET8 MAUI CollectionView and ItemsLayout is not working properly

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I have my `CollectionView` in a `MAUI` project with `NET8`. I defined the view as that

```
<CollectionView
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill"
    ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GameList}"
    VerticalOptions="Fill">
```

following the example in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/layout?view=net-maui-8.0#vertical-grid). The result is funny. As you can see in the following screenshot from the application running on Windows 11, there is an item on the left and a lot of space on the right.

[image]

If I resize the window, the render doesn't change.

[image]

I tried to change the `HorizontalOptions` but with the same result. Is this a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

### Update

The render of the component in Android is what I like to see also in Windows.

[image]

2 columns with the `DataTemplate`.

Comment: Could you please post the code of  your  `CollectionView.ItemTemplate`? And what kind of effect do you want?

Comment: Hi @Enrico, could you please post the code of your `CollectionView.ItemTemplate` ?